# Plotting xis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(20,25))
fig.suptitle('Distributions')

cols = df_train.columns
colindex = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        axes[i,j].hist(df_train[cols[colindex]])
        colindex += 1
```

It prints the following:

[image]
[image]

But I would like to add labels on the y and x-axis of each plot. Y is count, and X:s are different columns from a pandas dataframe inside the variable df_train.

Comment: Why not `axes[i,j].set_xlabel(cols[colindex]]` and `axes[i,j].set_ylabel('Count')`. You can call `plt.tight_layout()` at the end to make all labels fit nicely.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks a lot! I tried to use code to do a boxplot, but it didn't end up as I wished. Could you help in one more thing? :)